# preg_match used to work in code, but now does not define variable - broken code

Tags: php, mysql, preg-match

I am dumbfounded, as after no changes, my MySQL table update code has stopped working, printing the following error:

```
[23-Sep-2017 20:04:17 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: results in /home/harabla/public_html/testi/update.php on line 46
```

As said, I have not changed any parts of the code, but the only thing I can think of is that the `preg_match` on line 46 is not defining the variable results anymore for some reason. I'm wondering if I should be looking for a change that has happened on the target site that I am pulling from, or if there's something else I'm missing.

Here's the rest of the code:

```
<?php
$servername = "myserver";
$username = "user";
$password = "pass";
$dbname = "dbname";


// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: $conn->connect_error");
} 


$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id from users");
$userinfo = array();

while ($row_user = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
    $userinfo[] = $row_user;
}

foreach ($userinfo as $user) {
    $url = "http://www.pdga.com/player/$user[id]";
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $html = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);


    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($html);

    $xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
    $class = 'current-rating';
    $divs = $xpath->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $class ')]");

    foreach ($divs as $div) {
        preg_match('/Current Rating:\s+(\d+)/', $div->nodeValue, $results);
    }


    if (!is_null($results[1])){
        $sql = "UPDATE users SET rating = $results[1] WHERE id = $user[id]";
    } else {
        $sql = "UPDATE users SET rating = '0' WHERE id = $user[id]";
    }

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Record updated successfully <br>";
    } else {
        echo "Error updating record <br> $conn->error";
    }

    unset($results);
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: what if the curl query faces some error and returns you some random content without any <div> element ?

Comment: I guess it could, but I checked that url etc. and it should be fine.

Comment: Scratch that, just noticed they changed their urls to https. let me try

Comment: `var_dump($div->nodeValue)` give what? You also are open to SQL injections with this, parameterize.

Comment: idd. was as simple as that and I hadn't payed enough attention to it. Thanks

Comment: Probably use `followlocation`, http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php.

Comment: The variable `$results` is never set.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer was simple. the curl was accessing as http whereas the website in question had changed to https and I had not noticed. thank you for the help.

Comment: In this case, I suggest to delete the question. As an aside `foreach($divs as $div) {
    preg_match('/Current Rating:\s+(\d+)/', $div->nodeValue, $results);
}


if (!is_null($results[1])){` is a very strange design. I think you have to rewrite this.